# malloc and free in C

Tags: c, free

if I have something like

```
 struct Node *root;
 struct Node *q;

 root = malloc( sizeof(struct Node));
 q = root;
 free(q);
```

is the node q is pointing to freed?? or would I have to pass `root` to the `free` function?

Comment: Please note that `malloc` and `free` operate on *memory zones*, not on variables. You may have several variables holding the *same* pointer. Read about [pointer aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing)

Comment: I know about pointer aliasing, just not sure how free works

Comment: saying that free works on memory zones cleared it up though. thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `root` and `q` have the same value, that is to say, they point to the same memory location. After the call to `free(q)`, both of them are dangling pointers because the thing they both point to has been freed but they still point to that location.

To de-reference either would invoke undefined behaviour. This includes calling `free` on either of them.

Answer (score 1):

After calling `free(q)` the freed memory is not being cleared or erased in any manner.
Both `q` and `root` are still pointing to the allocated memory location but that memory location is added to the list of free memory chunks and can be re-allocated.  You are not allowed to reference that memory location by any of these pointers otherwise it will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: In some implementations (and notably for large memory blocks), `free` might sometimes release memory by giving it back to the operating system (e.g. with `munmap` on Linux or POSIX). But usually `free` simply makes the memory zone reusable for future `malloc`

Answer (score 1):

The pointers `q` and `root` point to the same block of memory after the assignment. So the call to `free` will free that block and both `q` and `root` are left dangling.

You can write

```
free(q);
```

or

```
free(root);
```

interchangeably since

```
q == root
```

Answer (score 0):

After `free` call both `q` and `root` point to freed memory block.

Generally, each resource has to be released only once. This is different from C++, where you can implement (but probably should not) pretty complex logic of resource management.